# Storing a hierarchy tree in SQL where each son can have several fathers

Tags: sql

I'm trying to store a hierarchical tree in SQL. In my case, the same son can have many fathers (the tree represents a VLSI design where the same cells can be used several times in different designs).
All models I've found on the web describe the employee/manager relationship where each employee has one manager.  In my case, the number of fathers can be quite large and if I try to store all of them in a table field, they can exceed the character limit of the field.
Can anyone suggest a better method for storing this tree ?

Thanks,

Meir

Comment: How many levels deep will the tree be? Only two, fathers and sons or do you have a grandson level which can also be multi-parent? Is another way of thinking about it to consider it an upside down tree or do connection fan out from either side of a son (if you see what I mean)? EDIT: in fact, are you storing a graph, not a tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to store this relationship in a relational database would be to create two tables - EMPLOYEE_TABLE and EMPLOYEE_MANAGERS_TABLE

```
create table EMPLOYEE_TABLE(
  emp_id number, 
  emp_name varchar(200),

  primary key(emp_id)
)


create table EMPLOYEE_MANAGERS_TABLE (
  id number,
  emp_id number, 
  manager_id number,

  primary key(id),
  foreign key(emp_id) references employee_table(emp_id),
  foreign key(manager_id) references employee_table(emp_id)
)
```

EMPLOYEE_MANAGERS_TABLE will contain one row per employee_manager relationship.

You can apply the same schema to store the father-son relationship where a son can have more than 1 father.

Answer (score 1):

Use a link table. I'm going to assume you are talking about people and will use that vernacular.

You have a person_table listing all the people and their respective id's. You then have a father_son_table describing the links between each person. Eg.

person_table

```
id   |   Name
1    |   Matthew
2    |   Mark
3    |   Luke
4    |   John
```

Say Matthew is Mark's father and Mark was father to Luke and John. In the father_son_table you would have:

father_son_table

```
id    | father_id | son_id
1     | 1         | 2
2     | 2         | 3
3     | 2         | 4
```

Here you can define as many fathers and sons as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! I'll try to use this approach as it seems most suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

> the number of fathers can be quite large and if I try to store all of them in a table field

eh? Your data is not normalised if you're trying to put multiple values in the same field.

While you say its hierarchical this usually implies that a node has a single 'parent' and 0 or more descendants. If that's not the case then its NOT a hierarchical data model - its a M:N relationship.

Or do you mean that there each node exists in more than one hierarchy?

The question is imposible to answer unless you provide an accurate description of the relationship between records.

Answer (score 0):

You find some clever methods for tree handling in the book of Joe Celko:

[http://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celkos-SQL-Smarties-Programming/dp/1558605762](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605762)

...however, I don't know if it covers your problem

Comment: Celko has a whole book on Trees and Hierarchies: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hierarchies-Smarties-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/1558609202

Answer (score 0):

I would go for additional many-to-many connection table with `father_id` and `son_id` columns.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider what queries you will most frequently be running against this table.  Different strategies for storing hierarchies have advantages / disadvantages based on how the hierarchy is used.

Also, any single-parent strategy for storing a hierarchy could be adapted to handle multiple parents simply by treating each element of the tree as a pointer.  Pointers under different parents could each point to the same record.